# AS3 XML Language file how do I use the id attribute?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Say I have the follwoing XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<language id="en" description="English">
    <start>Start</start>
    <instructions>some instructions</instructions>
</language>
```

---

**How can I adapt this code to switch between the language id values?** at the moment I get the error: Error #1069: Property language not found on String and there is no default value.

```
    private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {

        switch (e.target.data.language.@id) {
            case "en":
            _en = new XML(e.target.data);
            _en.ignoreWhitespace = true;
            break;

            case "de":
            _de = new XML(e.target.data);
            _de.ignoreWhitespace = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the XML before you accessing it. Also `<language>` is your root element, so you won't find children with this name.

```
private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {

    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data)

    switch (xml.@id.toString()) {
        case "en":
        _en = xml;
        _en.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        break;

        case "de":
        _de = xml;
        _de.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: great thanks, no more errors. Except the switch statement isn't working... I can trace(xml) and see it is there. any ideas?

Comment: it works with `var lang:String = xml.@id;` `switch (lang) {...` which seems odd

Comment: Ahh missed that, No, it's not odd, `xml.@id` is of type `XML` so there have to be a "cast" to string. Updated my answer.